# Javascript: XMLHttpRequst: How to make it work

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Given below is the simplest script I put together to test XMLHttpRequest. But, no matter what I do, I don't seem to be able get it working. It ALWAYS results in error after headers are received. One of the possibility is that it's because of proxy. If it is how can I know that's the cause? Please note the code for XMLHttpRequest is taken from guide at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/JavaScript">

function loadXMLDoc()
{

var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

oXHR.onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
  if (oXHR.readyState === 4) {
    if (oXHR.status === 200) {
      document.getElementById("xml_req_output").innerHTML += oXHR.responseText + "\n";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("xml_req_output").innerHTML += "Error:" + oXHR.statusText  + "\n";
    }
  }
}

if ( typeof oXHR.overrideMimeType != 'undefined') {
   oXHR.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
}

var urltoget = document.getElementById("txturl").value;

document.getElementById("xml_req_output").innerHTML += urltoget + "\n";

oXHR.open("GET", urltoget, true);
oXHR.send(null);

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="txturl" id="txturl" size="200" value="http://www.mozilla.org"/>
</br>
<input type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()" value="Get XML"/>
</br>
<textarea cols="100" rows="50" height="400px" id="xml_req_output" >
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Think of XMLHttpRequests as a way to talk to servers that want to talk to it.  So, if a server wants to talk to you, it will make provision to, either through the headers with CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing), with a special callback from JSON-P, or another means.  It is a built-in feature in JavaScript to not allow an XMLHttpRequest to another server, which is why you're having problems.  Try making a simple PHP script to test it on (from your server), and request that: `<?php echo "Ajax is working"; ?>`.  See what you get.

Comment: @TimBolton thanks for the comment (I wanted to accept that as an answer but didn't know how). Nor I know how to give points but +1 for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot load documents by XMLHttpRequest from diffent domains. See also the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).